# How to find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{(2k+1)(2n+1)^{2k+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

I want to evaluate  $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{(2k+1)(2n+1)^{2k+1}}$$

From $$\arctan{x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$
I get $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{(2k+1)(2n+1)^{2k+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$

I try to use telescopic method but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Let:
$$
\alpha(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\arctan\left(\frac{x}{2k+1}\right)(-1)^k
$$
Thus $\alpha(0)=0$. Then:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\alpha(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1) \left(\frac{x^2}{(2 n+1)^2}+1\right)}=\frac{\pi}{4\cosh\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}
$$
Integrating both sides we obtain:
$$
\alpha(x)=\arctan\left(\tanh\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)\right)+C
$$
Substituting $x=0$ we get $C=0$. Thus:
$$
\alpha(1)=\arctan\left(\tanh\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you.   but why $\alpha '(x)=\frac{\pi}{4\cosh{\frac{\pi x}{2}}}$ ?

Comment: @Bless thats the mittag-leffler representation of this function. u ma derive it from the product expansion of sin/cos

Comment: From this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function , what are value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?

Comment: @tired: I've tried to do just that, but I can't for the life of me see how.